# Example of MVC model request and post via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

This question undoubtedly has been asked and answered before, but I am looking for answers/examples relating to a specific scenario, so here goes...

I am doing an MVC 4 project for which almost all of the pages have grids (done via the jqGrid facility).  What I want is to have add and update forms contained in the same cshtml page, and called as jQuery popup dialogs.  The model for each page would therefore be defined to contain all of the fields necessary for both adding and updating the underlying entity, but would only be sent to the page when requested via an ajax call.

Therefore the flow would be as follows:

1. The page is requested, which calls the initial get controller method.
2. During the page load, the grid in the page does an ajax call to another controller method to load itself.
3. The user clicks a button to insert a new record or to edit an existing record.
4. An ajax call containing the appropriate keys is made to another controller method, requesting either a blank model (for inserting), or a populated model (for editing).  Blank models typically contain dropdown lists, so that are not actually "blank".  Then the jQuery modal dialog is displayed.
5. The user enters/edits the desired data and clicks a submit button. The model is then submitted to the post controller method which performs the necessary insert/update actions, and then returns to step #1.

I have to create pages for many entities, so I would like this is to be done in the simplest and most boilerplate way, with minimal code changes and re-engineering from page to page.

Is there a good example of this that I can review?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope [ASP.NET MVC-4,Entity Framework and JQGrid Demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801895/ASP-NET-MVC-Entity-Framework-and-JQGrid-Demo-wit) will help

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the grid stuff working.  The issue here is not the grid logic, but rather using a data entry form based on the model for the page (i.e., NOT using the jqGrid popup).

This would use a data entry window (a jQuery modal dialog) that would be displayed when the user clicks the add or the edit button. It will request the necessary data via ajax, and then open the dialog.

Comment: When the OK button in the dialog window is clicked, the model would be submitted to the server for processing, as would be done for a normal submit.  If validation errors are returned, the dialog window would remain open and display the errors.

Therefore it is the dialog functionality for which I am seeking help.

Comment: Sorry to have partial answering (that what might help you), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255821/how-to-submit-form-in-jquery-ui-dialog-and-display-its-response) might help